# My progress with Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I was here this morning asking on how to get started on bootstrap 3, some good fellows guided and supported me.

Attached is a picture of the progress I have made to far, I know there's still long way to go and I'm still learning. 
But right now, I'm stuck on this jumbotron part. I am trying to make the text and the picture to be horizontally align but I have been battling with it for hours. Can some one please help me out on how to go about it. Also, I will like to change the background color from what it is now to a different color.

Sorry I just realized that I'm not yet eligible to post and image.

Here is the script:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Jumbotron Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jumbotron.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Just for debugging purposes. Don't actually copy these 2 lines! -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="../../assets/js/ie8-responsive-file-warning.js"></script><![endif]-->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie-emulation-modes-warning.js"></script>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>

  <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Techy Support</a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="form">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Sign in</button>
          </form>
        </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
    <div id="home-page">
      <section class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
          <h1 class="mission-statement">
            Making IT at home <br /> 
            Easy and Affordable
            <div class="text-right">
          <img class="img-rounded"  style="width: 200px;" src="bac.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" />
          </div>
          </h1>


        </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    <!-- <div class="jumbotron">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Making IT at home <br> Easy and Affordable!</h1>
        <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called a jumbotron and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
        <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        <img class="jumbotron-image hidden-sm hidden-xs hidden-md" src="bac.jpg" />

      </div>
    </div> -->

    <div class="container">
      <!-- Example row of columns -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
       </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <h2>Heading</h2>
          <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
          <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <hr>

      <footer>
        <p>&copy; Company 2014</p>
      </footer>
    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../../dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="../../assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I'm sure some would understand the challenge I'm facing.

Thanks

Comment: Please share the complete code. A fiddle with your code will help a lot.

Comment: Alright thank you. I just updated it now

Comment: Can you change the question title to something more meaningful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the col-**-* classes provided by bootstrap for your layout. For background color, apply a `background-color` style to your jumbotron element.

```
<div id="home-page">
    <section class="jumbotron" style="background-color:#336699">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <h1 class="mission-statement">
            Making IT at home <br /> 
            Easy and Affordable
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <img class="img-rounded"  style="width: 200px;" src="mac.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/d5x2ho7r/1/

Comment: You have both class="img-rounded" and  class="img-responsive center-block" in your img tag. needs to be just one,  class="img-rounded img-responsive center-block"